# Detecting if a key was pressed, not if it is always down

Tags: c++, input, keyboard, mouse, sfml

I'm new to SFML and I have trouble finding a solution to checking if a key is pressed during one frame. The problem I've been facing is the fact that with the `Keyboard` and `Mouse` classes, it seems impossible to use a system where one first checks for the current input state before any `Update()` call of objects and then after all `Update()` you get a previous input state for the next frame so that one can do the following:

```
    bool Entity::KeyboardCheckPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key aKey)
    {
        //this part doesn't work 
        if (KeyboardState->isKeyPressed(aKey) and !PreviousKeyboardState->isKeyPressed(aKey))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work with SFML, and other sources tell me that I'm suppose to use the `Event` class with its `type` and `key.code`like the following example:

```
bool Entity::KeyboardCheckPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key aKey)
{
    if (Event->type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
    {
        if (Event->key.code == aKey)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

But this results in the `sf::Event::KeyPressed` doing the same as  `KeyboardState->isKeyPressed(aKey)`, so then I tried the method where you set key repeat to false: `window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);`with no results what so ever. I also found out that the `sf::Event::KeyPressed` works only as intended inside of this part in the main.cpp:

```
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{

}
```

The problem with this is that I want to handle Input inside of my Entity objects' `Update()`function, and I can't put the whole Update loop inside of the   `while (window.pollEvent(event))`. So here I am, struggling to find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *Why* do you want to handle input in your entityies `Update()` function?

Comment: @NaCl Maybe I didn't express myself correctly, what I mean is so that I can just say if(KeyboardCheckPressed(sf::Keyboard::aKey))//do something, inside of any object that inherits from the base Entity class.

Comment: write a wrapper class containing a bunch of booleans that get updated exactly when you want them to be updated

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a thing which you can check the current state of, and you want to check if that state changed between frames, you simply use a variable, declared outside the application loop, to store the previous state, and compare it to the current state.

```
bool previousState = checkState();
while (true) {
    // your main application loop

    bool newState = checkState();
    if (newState == true && previousState == false) {
        doThingy("the thing went from false to true");
    } else if (newState == false && previousState == true) {
        doThingy("the thing went from true to false");
    } else {
        doThingy("no change in the thing");
    }

    // this is done unconditionally every frame
    previousState = newState;
}
```